# When I open the given url by selenium the server says it can't process my request

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, httprequest

That is my code.

```
public void getDeliveryStatus(String carrier, String trackingNumber) {
        String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36 OPR/60.0.3255.170";
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("start-maximized");
        options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", new String[]{"enable-automation"});
        options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
        options.addArguments("general.useragent.override", userAgent);
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.get("https://www.fedex.com/apps/fedextrack/?tracknumbers=286361067505");
    }
```

This is the error.

[image]

And that is the error on the console.

[image]

Comment: Looks like you missing  headers

Comment: I added the requested header but nothing changed

Comment: Please update your question with code with the header and it's output.